# count with has_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got an `Order` and `Orderdetails`

```
Orderdetails belongs_to Order

Order has_many Orderdetails
```

I am trying to convert the following query to ActiveRecord `count` function

```
select Count(*) 
from orderdetails A, orders B 
where A.prodid='6' and A.orderid= B.id and B.custid='11'
```

I tried:

```
@count = Orderdetail.count(:conditions => "prodid = 6 and order.custid = 11")
```

However, this gives error:

```
PGError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "order"
LINE 1: ...unt_all FROM "orderdetails" WHERE (prodid = 6 and order.cust...
```

**Edit**
I changed to order**s**

but now i get this error:

> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause
>   entry for table "orders" LINE 1:
>   ...unt_all FROM "orderdetails" WHERE
>   (prodid = 6 and orders.cus...

Comment: shouldn't the table's name be "orders"?

Comment: dope. that fixed something. now i get different error. how do i add orders in the from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `:joins => :order'`, because your condition contains element from orders table (that's why you get error `missing FROM-clause`), try:

```
@count = Orderdetail.count(:joins => :order, :conditions => "prodid = 6 and orders.custid = 11")
```

Also it better (safer) to use array in conditions:

```
@count = Orderdetail.count(:joins => :order, :conditions => ["prodid = ? and orders.custid = ?", 6, 11])
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should thoroughly read some docs on how associations work in rails. [Try this guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

You don't need to write any SQL in `:conditions` to do what you need.

Comment: that guide mentions nothing about how to do count by activerecord?

Comment: After you're familiar with how associations work you can start reading docs: Like the docs for `count` - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html#M002187